# Young modulus in Hooke's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

This is the question:

[image]

And the answer is:

[image]

I understand the $2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-2l$ part but how does Young modulus $\lambda/2l$ equal the spring constant?

Shouldn't it be $\lambda \times A/2l$ where A is the cross-sectional area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (some) Mathematicians Hooke’s law is the proportionality between the force and the **fractional** change in the length and they call the constant of proportionality the “modulus os elasticity” and denote it using the symbol $\lambda$.  Thus for these Mathematicians $\lambda$, the modulus of elasticity, is not the same a Young’s modulus.
In your example the spring constant, often denoted by symbol $k$, $k=\frac {\lambda}{2l}$ with $2l$ being the original length of the string.